# Masking a Numpy array multiple times produces wrong result

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to mask a single array in multiple locations based on conditions from two other arrays. When I do so and then plot the original array and the arrays it was masked against, the data is not consistently masked in the correct places. Below is a working example code that reproduces the problem as well the resulting plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f1 = np.random.randint(51, size=150)
lt_vals = np.arange(0,25,1)
alt_vals = np.arange(0,15,1)
alt = np.tile(alt_vals,10)
lt = np.tile(lt_vals, 6)
x_vals = range(len(f1))

f1m = np.ma.masked_where((lt>5) & (lt<20), f1)
f1am = np.ma.masked_where(alt>5, f1m)


variables = [f1am, alt, lt]
ylabels = ['Function', 'Sim Alt', 'Sim Time']
number_of_subplots= len(variables)

plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
for i,j,k in zip(range(number_of_subplots), variables, ylabels):  
    ax1 = plt.subplot(number_of_subplots,1,i+1)
    ax1.plot(x_vals,j)
    ax1.set_ylabel(k)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example from Code]

As you can see, the data in the top panel should be masked anywhere the second panel is greater than 5 and anywhere the third panel is greater than 5 but less than 20. The second set of data displayed in the top panel are obviously displaying at alts greater than 5, which is exactly my problem. Anyone have any guesses for how to get the right behavior out of this? Thanks!

-Will

Comment: Are you aware that the first plot is on a different horizontal scale from the others? The `alt` data corresponding to a part of the first plot isn't directly under that part.

Comment: Can you explain your question, maybe by example or any other way

Comment: I'm aware but maybe that is my issue actually. If I test len(f1am) == len(alt) == len(lt) I get True. So why is the first plot getting offset from the others? They are being plotting vs the same x range of values.

Comment: @ChaosPredictor I am trying to mask the f1 array where the alt and lt arrays satisfy some condition. So in my example, for all indices where alt is greater than 5, I want those same indices masked in the f1 array. Same goes for lt.

Comment: The first plot's data ends earlier (because the rest is masked), so what data is there gets more room.

Comment: Evidently masking affects the `x` axis range (as a default).  Go to your plot and set the `x` range to 0 and 150 for all subplots (or do that in the code).  And also look at the arrays to verify which elements are masked.  The masks have a different periodicity (25 and 10), so their overlap can be confusing.  But when test it, it looks right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The masking is definitely working correctly in the code from the question. You can visualize the ranges that get masked with `fill_between`. Also, sharing all axes makes it easier to compare the three plots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["axes.xmargin"] = 0
plt.rcParams["axes.ymargin"] = 0

f1 = np.random.randint(51, size=150)
lt_vals = np.arange(0,25,1)
alt_vals = np.arange(0,15,1)
alt = np.tile(alt_vals,10)
lt = np.tile(lt_vals, 6)
x_vals = range(len(f1))

f1m = np.ma.masked_where((lt>5) & (lt<20), f1)
f1am = np.ma.masked_where(alt>5, f1m)


variables = [f1am, alt, lt]
ylabels = ['Function', 'Sim Alt', 'Sim Time']
number_of_subplots= len(variables)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)
for i,j,k in zip(range(number_of_subplots), variables, ylabels):  
    ax1 = axes[i]
    ax1.plot(x_vals,j, marker=".")
    ax1.set_ylabel(k)

axes[1].fill_between(x_vals,alt.max(),0, where=alt>5, alpha=0.2)
axes[2].fill_between(x_vals,lt.max(),0, where=(lt>5) & (lt<20), alpha=0.2)
axes[0].fill_between(x_vals,51,0, where=((lt>5) & (lt<20)) | (alt>5) , alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

There are some single points outside the masked area which will not be shown in a line plot, so you can use a marker `"."` to show them.

Comment: When I get into the office tomorrow morning I will check to see if this fixes the issue. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Do you know why the stripes on your plot aren't quite vertical? It's not an optical illusion; inspecting the image at high zoom shows the left edge of every blue stripe is slightly tilted.

Comment: I'm not sure what this would fix, it's more to show that the code is actually correct. The span edges were indeed not vertical due to the `interpolate=True` I used. I left that out, now its vertical. In any case those spans are just there to help visualizing the masked regions.